# How to create Achievements

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, achievements

"Each game gets a total of 1000 points to distribute across all their achievements."

Is that means that, for example, I can create ten 100 points achievements and that's it, or it means that if I have a 100 points achievement I can't give it to more than 10 people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1000 point limit for the sum total of all of your application's achievements, so if you have 10 achievements worth 100 points each, you've run out of achievements you can setup within Facebook. The 1000 point limit is not a shared limit between all users, it's simply meant to enforce a distribution curve that allows Facebook to decide which achievements are more notable to share.

Comment: If I create only one achievement URL but I'm referring to it each time with a different description (there's a user name inside of it being set using a query string value being passed to this URL) - can it be that Facebook refers to it each time as a different achievement? cause I'm getting an error that I passed the achievement points of my app.